# Mapping Json with general model for response and exceptions

Tags: spring-mvc

sorry for my bad english in advance :/

I would like to build response from RestController, to any object, with a general model in json like this :

meta:{"status":httpstatus},
data: {"response" : response}

and for exceptions :

meta: {"status" : httpstatus, "errorCode":"code", "message": "message"},
data:{}

there is "HttpMessageConverter" and Objectmapper but i don't know how to use this in my case
objectmapper use "serializer" from jackson, but for one object ?

Spring 4.1.3

Edit :

like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("..")
public class XXX {


@RequestMapping("..,consume/produce Json")
public ResponseEntity<T> method(@RequestBody arg)

T objectToReturn = ... ;


return new ResponseEntity<T>(objectToReturn, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

...
}
```

Comment: Can  you include your controller method code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your straightforward case,  you can getaway with Jackson 2, to ignore null fields when serializing a java class.

Your controller could be as follows

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> method(@RequestBody @Valid arg,BindingResult result){
        ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> response = null;
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            Meta meta = new Meta(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            ResponseStatus body = new ResponseStatus(meta,null);
            response = ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(body);
        }else{
              Meta meta = new Meta(HttpStatus.CREATED);
              Data data = service.data(arg);
              response = ResponseEntity.created(new URI("location"))
                         .body(new ResponseStatus(meta,data));
        }
        return response;
    }
```

And other classes will be

```
//Ignore Null Fields on the Class
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class ResponseStatus{
 @Getter @Setter Meta meta;
 @Getter @Setter Data data;

 public ResponseStatus(Meta meta, data){
    this.meta = meta;
    this.data = data;
  }
}

//Ignore Null Fields on the Class
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
class Meta{

 @Getter @Setter int status;
 @Getter @Setter String errorCode;
 @Getter Setter message;

 public Meta(HttpStatus httpStatus){
   status = httpStatus.value();
   message = httpStatus.getReasonPhrase();
   errorCode ="You code specific here";

 }
}
```